# If I download a sub-theme do I install it under the main theme's directory?

Tags: theming

For example, I found [this theme](https://drupal.org/project/tb_purity), which says it requires the Nucleus Base theme.

Does that mean that I need to install it in the Nucleus Base theme directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should install it under main themes directory i.e. `sites/all/themes`.

1. Download Nucleus Base theme and put it inside `sites/all/themes/` folder
2. Download TB Purity theme and put it inside `sites/all/themes/` folder.
3. Go to **Appearance** and enable TB Purity theme.

The concept of base theme is it provides code base to its sub-theme, so, you don't really need to enable Base theme, just keep it there for your Sub-theme to find the codes that it needs to run.

Answer (score 2):

You install it as other themes that are not sub-themes of other themes, in its own directory of the theme directory.

You could install it in a sub-directory of the directory containing the theme from which the sub-theme depends, and Drupal would find it the same. The problem would be when you update the parent theme, as you would risk to lose the sub-theme's files.
It is like with modules: You don't install a module inside the directory containing another module, if not in the case both modules are part of the same project hosted on Drupal.org, and you get them in the same archive file.

Answer (score 0):

It is still added to Drupal in the same way as other contributed themes are added, in the `sites/all/themes` folder.

The 'requires Nucleus Base Theme' just means that the nucleus base theme also has to be installed on the site.